# Error spliting by backslash a text obtained in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, split

I'm currently working on HMI tests. For one of those tests, i would like to get some text on a page to use it later.

The structure of the HTML code is like so :

```
<span class="class1">
   The text I want to get
   <span class="class2">
      <span class="class3">1</span>
      <i class="class4">
         ::before
      </i>
   </span>
</span>
```

The text i would like to get is in the span with `class="class1"`. In order to do that, i have this :

```
text_i_want = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.class1').text
```

The output i have however is `The text I want to get\n1`. I would like to get rid of this \n1 in my string, and to do that, I used this :

```
text_i_want = text_i_want.split("\\")[0]
```

However, the output is still `The text I want to get\n1`. Plus, here are 2 important points:

- The argument is `"\\"`, because if there is only one backslash, i get a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`
- I tried `print(repr(text_i_want))` to see if the string i was getting in output was different from what I saw on the console, but it's still the same.

Do you guys know how to solve this ?

### **Note**

I tried the solutions exposed here : [Split a string by backslash in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047976/split-a-string-by-backslash-in-python). It didn't work for some reasons ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on `"\n"`. Try:

```
text_i_want = text_i_want.split("\n")[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But It won't be the case if there is no 'n' after the backslash. Do you have any idea how to manage this case ?

Comment: @ZoulouDu94 ``` .split("\\") ``` will work for "\".  The character "\n" is read by the computer as one character so you will not be able to split the "\" out of the "\n"

Comment: Any time. This could also apply to "\r". See this wiki page for new line values.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

Try Python [splitlines()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/splitlines) function.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.class1").text.splitlines()[0])
```